# Post string to Rest API results in 400 Bad Request

Tags: json, rest, asp.net-core, bad-request, .net-core-2.2

Sending a post request with a *json* object transformed into HttpContent, but the result is a 400 Bad request.

Sender

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
               .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var jsonObject = new JObject(new JProperty("id", Id), new JProperty("image", face));
var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
var response = _client.PostAsync(_settings.Uri, 
                   new StringContent(strJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Receiver

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
```

Could you please give me an advise on how to overcome 400 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code sends an **object** serialized to `json` while `ASP.NET Core` action expects a **string** serialized to `json`. The easiest solution would be repeated data serialization

```cs
var objectJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
var stringJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectJson);
var response = _client.PostAsync(_settings.Uri, new StringContent(stringJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, what is the best way to do it? thanks!

Comment: @DanielV In my opinion the current way is a pretty good way to do it since `JsonConvert` guarantees you a valid json string. Probably it will be more performant to enclose `objectJson` result in double quotes manually but you have to care about proper escaping such double quotes inside string.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have an extra Parentheses in your call

```
var response = _client.PostAsync(_settings.Uri, (new StringContent(strJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

**(**new

Try removing that first.

Cheers

Comment: Hey, pretty sure, that is not the issue, I tried to simplify just for the sake of this question. You can go ahead and edit